# High speed transcoding image data from a gigE camera

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, transcoding, gige-sdk

I have an 8 mp  (3296 x 2472) gigE camera that is capable of running at around 25 fps with 14bit Bayer encoded frames.

I have code (using the vimba api) that can capture frames at full rate and wrote the raw data to disk.  However, we also wish to implement a network stream of this video feed and don't have the bandwidth to broadcast the frames in the raw naive format.

Ultimately, I think I want to create an h.264 network stream from the frames, but I'm not sure a normal computer is going to be able to transcode that at the data rates I'm running.  So I'm thinking I might need to use a GPU or some other hardware accelerator.

Does anyone have any specific advice on where to start

Answer (score 0):

GPUs or FPGAs are where to go.  Which is best depends on your specific needs but I think GPUs make more sense for most people.

Take a look at NVENC for Nvidia's library dedicated to doing real time video encoding.  You may not have to get your hands too wet.

A note that the debayer operation can also be done on the GPU but I'm not sure if you can avoid a round-trip transfer while using the NVENC api - it may be insignificant though with these numbers.

update: [now amd has a library](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amdcompress/)